# I'm writing a book and refer to quick references to spark creativity but also learn other words to improve my vocabulary. Is this plagiarism?

Tags: citations, plagiarism

If you're a writer and you pull other words from an author's work to apply to your own vocabulary and work, just words, not full on sentences, is that considered plagiarism? I'm trying to learn and improve as a writer so when I'm reading other books from other authors and come across words I've never used, and from there, begin to use and apply them to my own vocabulary, is that plagiarism? I just want to ensure I'm not violating any rights or incidentally plagiarizing. I'm very torn on this. Can someone help?

Comment: I do not think that it falls under the formal definition of plagiarism, however I am not sure whether such a thing is within the spirit of plagiarism. In any case, I want to point out that this is a very good question which will probably be particularly appealing for people for whom english is the second language (including yours truly).

Comment: You can't protect a language as "intellectual property". You seem to be following a good practice on improving language skills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, plagiarism is copying someone else's work and trying to pass it off as your own. If you only pull isolated words, you aren't copying anyone's work, because the "work" is deciding to use that word in a given context, and your context isn't the same.

Answer (score 1):

Plagiarism comes into play only when use use the work of another without proper attribution. I don't suppose would be called *plagiarising* the work of another by merely utilising the vocabulary.

The following are the things you should watch out for:

- Copying whole sentences
- Copying the base/novel concepts themselves (even with rewording/rephrasing)
- Copying figures
- Copying tabulation

If any of the above is done *without citation*, it could be recalled as plagiarism. Furthermore it is always advisable to use figures and tables with permission from the publisher and first author (depending on the copyright policy of the respective article).